# Cant get all the values in php when I submit form

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I am trying to get the values of the HTML fields onto php and I can only see a few coming through using a `print_r ($_REQUEST)` .

So with the current html (http://pastebin.com/SDjZQCxD) i can't get anything through that is inside the div userData.

If I move the contents of that div above  `input id="submit-addItem" type="button" value="Add my item" style="display: block; display: none;" />` then strangely enough I can see the values in php using the get ..(so it works)

However I am puzzled in regards to why ..
I mean I want to leave the elements as it and they are all inside the form so I am not sure  why if I move them above the submit-additem it works but otherwise it doesn't..

The html code can be found here http://pastebin.com/SDjZQCxD

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange things occurs when you have multiple nested form tags.

I will suggest to remove the `<form name="aaa2">` tag and try it, that why. I don't see any usage for that second form.

Answer (score 1):

Well one of the main issues I think is that you have a form nested in another form. [You shouldn't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms).

Another reason is that I believe that the = character in your inputs is restricted. That might cause some weird issues for you.

```
<input class="styleA" id="item-location=ad1" name="item-location=ad1" type="text" value="Address Line 1" />
```

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Answer (score 0):

If a form field is not rendered because of a CSS style (in this case, `display: none;`), it will typically not be submitted via. post. (I say "typically" because [the language in the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) says that these hidden controls "may" be successful, but my experience is that most browsers will ignore them as if they were disabled).

Instead of `display: none;`, try using `visibility: hidden;` and `position: absolute;`. You'll get the same visual effect, but the hidden form controls will be submitted.